# A GRE verbal sentence equivalence question

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have a question concerning about the following GRE exercise:

> In noting that critical and popular opinions about Li’s art coincided, Chuang _____ the existence of an exception to her general theory of art criticism, which posits that critics’ views do not intersect with those of the general public.
>
> A.asserted
>
> B.conceded
>
> C.acknowledged
>
> D.doubted
>
> E.pondered
>
> F.questioned

The official answer is BC, while I believe that DF is also correct. Does "In noting that critical and popular opinions about Li’s art coincided, " give any useful information for deciding to choose BC(positive) or DF(negative) for the second half of the sentence? If the first half was

> Since he/she **believes** that critical and popular opinions about Li’s art **always** coincided, ...

Then I would have no doubt in choosing DF, and if the first half was

> **Although** critical and popular opinions about Li’s art **always** coincided,...

then the answer would surely be BC. But I think the meaning of "in noting that" lacks the essential emotional tendency for deciding the answer.

Comment: She is observing a *fact*, not a *possibility*. At this point, there's nothing to doubt or to question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  but I think she can still doubt or question anything that goes against the fact that she observed.

Comment: Once she has acknowledged a fact that contradicts her theory, she can no longer doubt or question the existence of an exception to her theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @michael.hor257k.

Point 1: Chuang notes that critical and popular opinions about Li’s art coincide.

Point 2: Given Point 1, Chuang has no choice but to *concede* or *acknowledge* the existence of an exception to her general theory of art criticism, which posits that critics’ views do not intersect with those of the general public.

*Asserted* doesn't work because Chuang' *concession* or *acknowledgment* in Point 2 is conditioned by her observation in Point 1. That is, it is in response to it. Of the possible answers, only *conceded* and *acknowledged* convey this sense.

*Doubted* doesn't work because Chuang accepts the statement in Point 1, leaving herself no logical alternative but to accept the statement in Point B. There is (can be) no *doubt* given Point 1.

Neither **pondered** nor **questioned** works for the same reason *doubted* doesn't work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think my problem is not on the logic of the whole sentence but on the grammar. The subject of the attributive clause("which posits that critics’ views do not intersect with those of the general public") is "her general theory of art criticism" instead of "an exception", but why?

Comment: @TiWen Thanks. I understand your issue better now. Two reasons. First, "which posits ..." is closer to "general theory of art criticism" than to "exception". Second, theories "posit", exceptions do not. So ""which posits ..." attaches to "general theory", not "exception".